# Space-char gets strangely formatted when Windows is set to english region format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I feel like I'm missing something completely obvious, but I ran into a failing test today that seems to point to a (malformed?) space character

I have a const declared like this:

`private const char ValueSeparator = ' ';`

This is just a space character (ASCII 32). However, Visual Studio seems to transform this into `32''` when the region format in Windows is set to "English (United Kingdom)". If I change it to "English (Germany)", the character gets displayed as expected. This doesn't seem like just a display error, since the Immediate Window prints the same string:

[image]

I am aware of region differences with different decimal separators etc, but I'm completely lost on how that would affect a plain space character.

The code in question hasn't been touched in years, and it doesn't seem to include a "false" whitespace-esque Unicode character. I've even re-typed the space explicitly.

This is the Windows setting that causes the issue:
[image]

I'm on VS 16.8.6. Can anyone enlighten me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're missing the forest for the trees. The Visual Studio debugging visualizer, including the Immediate Window, is merely showing the ASCII integer value of the character in question in front of the actual value, as a debugging aid.